# Error when trying to connect to civicrm from gmail using civigmail chrome extension by vedaconsulting: Error unsupported response type

Tags: extension

I am having trouble getting the civicrm gmail chrome extension to work. I am using the intructions here https://vedaconsulting.co.uk/civigmail-chrome-extension. When I click on the "connect civi" button that is added to my gmail page I get an oauth login page for my site but after entering in the correct information the following error flashes across the top of my screen.

- CiviCRM 4.7.17
- Civicrm ext: Gmailapi 1.0-alpha1
- Chrome: 57.0.2987.133
- Chrome ext: CiviGmail 0.2.1

Error message

- error: unsupported response type
- error description: implicit grant type not supported
- state: null

Any help on this would be appreciated

Regards
Steven

Comment: pls ensure you state your civi version and extension version etc

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the oauth login to work by checking "Allow the implicit flow" on the basic settings for the oauth2 server I setup.

/admin/structure/oauth2-servers/manage/[server-name]